# Why single element hashtable behaves differently in powershell?

Tags: powershell

Code sample:

```
function ToArray([hashtable] $hashTable){
    $ret = @()
    foreach($key in $hashTable.Keys){
        $ret += ("`"" + $key + ":" + $hashTable[$key] + "`"")
    }
    $ret
}


$h1 = @{
    key1 = "value1" # Only one key in this one
}

$h2 = @{
    key2 = "value2"
    key3 = "value3"
}

$h3 = @{
    key4 = "value4"
    key5 = "value5"
}


$test1 = ToArray $h1
$test1 += ToArray $h3

$test2 = ToArray $h2
$test2 += ToArray $h3

Write-Host
Write-Host "TEST 1:" $test1
Write-Host "TEST 2:" $test2
```

Output:

```
TEST 1: "key1:value1""key5:value5" "key4:value4"
TEST 2: "key3:value3" "key2:value2" "key5:value5" "key4:value4"
```

Question:
Why there is a missing space in TEST 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the following at the end of your script:

```
PS Y:\> $test1.GetType()
PS Y:\> $test2.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType            
-------- -------- ----                                     --------            
True     True     String                                   System.Object       
True     True     Object[]
```

One is of type `String` and the other an `Object Array`, when you have a single element hashtable, `PowerShell` sees it as a single string when assigning it to a variable.

```
PS Y:\> $test1 = ToArray $h1
PS Y:\> $test1.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

So `PowerShell` will then concatenate all the elements in `$h3` into one large string when using `+=`, as you are adding a `Array` to a `String`.

Whereas `$test2` to you are adding an `Array` to and `Array` meaning you will see the output as one larger array output.

To get round this explicitly define `$test1`'s type to and Array:

```
[array]$test1 = $h1
```

Comment: I had a feeling, that it was a string, but how can ToArray possibly return a string if I explicitly do $ret = @() inside it?

Comment: @Eiver ToArray is returning an array of 1 element, which when assigned to a variable which hasn't been previously define `PowerShell` will take the string value of the object rather than the array its self so you end up with the same thing.

Comment: Bizarrely, if I add [array] and run the script once and remove it, then PowerShell ISE will "remember" it is an array type until I restart it. Very weird and inconsistent behavior.

Comment: @Eiver Yes is happens in mine too, your ISE will keep track of all your variable between runs.